# AED8C8C1CAC0 SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, sql

when i am trying to execute sql procedure (call statement) and it gives me this error : "AED8C8C1CAC0 SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on best_avg(tbl_name)' at line 1"

this code deletes the indexes for each table with field more than one

and there are no ideas how to fix it..

here is the code:

is the cause in execute statement ?
then how can that operation be performed?)

```
 delimiter &&
 CREATE PROCEDURE dropping_indexes_excpt_for_primaryone()
 BEGIN 
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE tbl_name VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT '';
    
    DECLARE all_tables_cursor CURSOR for 
     (SELECT TABLE_NAME
      FROM information_schema.tables
      WHERE table_schema = DATABASE()
      AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE');
    
    DECLARE CONTINUE handler FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
    
    OPEN all_tables_cursor;
    tables_loop: LOOP
        fetch all_tables_cursor INTO tbl_name;
        if done then
            leave tables_loop;
        END if;
        BLOCK2: BEGIN 
        DECLARE index_name VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT '';
        
        DECLARE done_attr INT DEFAULT 0;
        
        DECLARE all_indexes_cursor CURSOR FOR 
            (SELECT index_name  FROM information_schema.STATISTICS AS inf
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = tbl_name AND table_schema= DATABASE() AND inf.index_name <>'PRIMARY' 
                GROUP BY inf.index_name
                HAVING COUNT(*)>1
            );
            
        DECLARE CONTINUE handler FOR NOT FOUND SET done_attr = 1;
        
        OPEN all_indexes_cursor; 
        indexes_loop: LOOP
            fetch all_indexes_cursor INTO index_name;
            if done_attr then leave indexes_loop;
            END if;
            
            SET @tmp = CONCAT('drop index ',index_name, ' on ', tbl_name);
            PREPARE dropping FROM @tmp;
            EXECUTE dropping;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE dropping;        
            END loop indexes_loop;
        close all_indexes_cursor;
        END BLOCK2;     
        END loop tables_loop;
    close all_tables_cursor;
    END;
&&
        
DROP PROCEDURE dropping_indexes_excpt_for_primaryone    
CALL dropping_indexes_excpt_for_primaryone()
```

2 approaches were taken by me
the first is i replaced the "drop index" statement with "alter table"
and the second one is that i used "drop index" without an execute clause (but that didn`t work because tabl and index are strings)

Comment: I don't see `best_avg` in the code you posted.

Comment: that is just the name of the table in the loop from my db

Comment: I suggest you need to look at the value of `@tmp` after you have formatted the dynamic SQL statement. Once you look at it, the syntax error might be more apparent.

Comment: Is this a one off exercise?

Comment: yep, thank you!
that is the thing (by some reason the index isnt added)